# Custom shader casts shadows but cannot receive them

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, rendering

I have two shaders for my 2d sprites to cast shadows when they are "stood up" 10 degrees off a flat plane.

This one casts and receives shadows, but I cannot use the alpha channel, transparency is entirely ignored

```
    Shader "Custom/SpriteShadow" 
{
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [PerRendererData]_MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Cutoff("Shadow alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags 
        { 
            "Queue"="Geometry"
            "RenderType"="TransparentCutout"
        }
        LOD 200

        Cull Off

        CGPROGRAM
        // Lambert lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Lambert addshadow fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        fixed4 _Color;
        fixed _Cutoff;

        struct Input
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
            clip(o.Alpha - _Cutoff);
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

The second shader can cast shadows and works with alpha/transparency, but cannot receive shadows.

```
Shader "Custom/SpriteShadowWithAlpha"{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}  
        _EffectColor1("Effect Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Crossfade("Fade", float) = 0
        _FlashColor("Flash Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _FlashAmount("Flash Amount",Range(0.0,1.0)) = 0
        _Cutoff("Alpha Cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.9
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    [Toggle(_ALPHABLEND_ON)] ALPHABLEND_ON("Enable Dithered Shadows", Float) = 0.0
 
 
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
            "RenderType" = "TransparentCutOut"
            "PreviewType" = "Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas" = "True"
        }
 
        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma surface surf Lambert alpha:blend fullforwardshadows alphatest:_Cutoff
            #pragma target 3.0
 
            struct Input {
                fixed2 uv_MainTex;
                fixed4 color : COLOR;
            };
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            fixed4 _EffectColor1;
            fixed _Crossfade;
            fixed4 _FlashColor;
            float _FlashAmount;
            void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
                fixed4 returnColor = lerp(col, col * _EffectColor1, _Crossfade) * _EffectColor1.a + col * (1.0 - _EffectColor1.a);
                o.Albedo = returnColor.rgb * IN.color.rgb;
                o.Alpha = col.a * IN.color.a;
                o.Albedo = lerp(o.Albedo,_FlashColor.rgb,_FlashAmount);
         
            }
        ENDCG
    }
    Fallback "Standard"
}
```

I have tried mixing and matching different parts of the two but can never get shadows to cast and receive and work with the alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer anyone in the future wants to see, but it is the one I went with. Originally I was unable to figure out a URP shader to do what I wanted. I was however able to find one that suited my needs later on.

So my solution was to upgrade to URP and ditch the standard shader. Using the following video as a guide and shader source
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_OBjV7c1CY